# Android failed to loop through all the Numbers in Gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview

I try to use Gridview to display total number of Tables in a Restaurant. User can set the total number of Tables by integer.

Each table has an ID starting from 1. However, all my table numbers are the same. Looks like something is wrong with the loop?

```
class my_adapter extends BaseAdapter{

LayoutInflater inflater=null;
Context ctx;
int table_count;

my_adapter(Context ctx, int table_count){
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.table_count=table_count;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return table_count; // total no. of tables
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row=view;

    if(row==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single,null);
    }

    TextView tv_table_no=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.table_no);

    for(int count=1;count<=table_count;count++){
        tv_table_no.setText("table number: "+count);
    }

    return row;
}
}
```

If table_count is 9, then there will be 9 tables with table no. from 1- 9.

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
for(int count=1;count<=table_count;count++){
    tv_table_no.setText("table number: "+count);
}
```

by

```
    tv_table_no.setText("table number: "+i);
```

Hope for the best!

Answer (score 1):

This for loop is wrong

```
for(int count=1;count<=table_count;count++){
            tv_table_no.setText("table number: "+count);
        }
```

Here for loop not required. modify your code write like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row=view;

    if(row==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single,null);
    }

    TextView tv_table_no=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.table_no);


        tv_table_no.setText("table number: "+(i+1)); //i is the position


    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping in your `getView()` method.
Actually `getView()` method calls according to `getCount()` method.

Remove the `for` loop and set the the value of `i` instead of count on `TextView`.

Simply replace the method `getView()` with:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);    

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single,null);

    TextView tv_table_no=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.table_no);

    tv_table_no.setText("table number: "+i);

    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well You put Count inside the for loop so it shows You Last position.please put it outside of for loop.